# Property MouseEvent.button doesn't work on mouseover event

Tags: javascript

I'd like to catch the mouse left button on a td element in a table.
I wrote the function dis() and I used the MouseEvent.button property in it.

```
function dis() {
        if (k && event.button == 0) {
            event.target.style.backgroundColor = "black";
        }
    }
```

The function is triggered by a onmouseover event. I noticed that in this case the event.button's value is always equal to 0, regardless of which button is pressed or not.
I noticed that if the function is triggered by a mousedown event the value changes according to the pressed button.

Thanks for helping

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to pass event into your `dis` function:

```
function dis(event) {
   if (k && event.button == 0) {
       event.target.style.backgroundColor = "black";
   }
}
```

Otherwise it will generate an error: `Cannot read property 'button' of undefined`

Answer (score 0):

In javascript, if a function is called by an event you can put this event in the parameters of this function.

so in your code you should pass the event as parameters of the function :

```
function dis(event) {
    if (k && event.button == 0) {
        event.target.style.backgroundColor = "black";
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried this code, but the event.button's value is always equal to 0.
    function dis(event) {
            document.getElementById("cas").value = event.button;
            if (k && event.button == 0) {
                event.target.style.backgroundColor = "black";
            }
        }

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script src="../Scripts/jquery-3.4.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script language="javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('.mouseclik tr td').mousedown(function (e) {

                if (e.which == 3) {
                    e.target.style.backgroundColor = "black";
                    return false;
                }
                return true;
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form >
    <div>
        <table id='MouseLeftClick' class='mouseclik'>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    Column one
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    Column Two
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    Column Three
                </td>
            </tr>`enter code here`
        </table>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```